# How to create an array with different data types in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

From what articles I read I would have to create it like such:

```
fileList = np.array[("chris.txt", 2569437), ("terry.dat", 4596), ("mike.doc", 6593543),
                 ("sarah.txt", 458667), ("david.ppt", 56437456), ("flyer.jpg", 4305),
                 ("fred.png", 54966), ("randy_.ocx", 5968434), ("terry.dmg", 54485656)
                 ("rick.exe", 4538565)]
```

But it's giving me an error of " '(str, int)' object is not callable". What am I doing wrong? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: You have to surround everything with `()` - `array` accepts a single value. Your error is because you forgot a `,` on the 3d line. Also, Array is probably not the type that's best for this - consider a dictionary.

Comment: You're missing a comma. Please delete your question.

Comment: Do you want an array of strings, or a structured array with one field of strings, the other integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileList = np.array([("chris.txt", 2569437), ("terry.dat", 4596), ("mike.doc", 6593543),
                 ("sarah.txt", 458667), ("david.ppt", 56437456), ("flyer.jpg", 4305),
                 ("fred.png", 54966), ("randy_.ocx", 5968434), ("terry.dmg", 54485656),
                 ("rick.exe", 4538565)])
```

You're missing the parenthesis to call `array(...)`, and you're missing a comma after `("terry", ...)`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't see that. Slightly embarrased XD

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma in between the last elements - python thinks that the last element is

```
("terry.dmg", 54485656) ("rick.exe", 4538565)
```

eg - trying to call `("terry.dmg", 54485656)` with 2 arguments: `"rick.exe", 4538565`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off. Try:

```
fileList = np.array([("chris.txt", 2569437), ("terry.dat", 4596), ("mike.doc", 6593543),
             ("sarah.txt", 458667), ("david.ppt", 56437456), ("flyer.jpg", 4305),
             ("fred.png", 54966), ("randy_.ocx", 5968434), ("terry.dmg", 54485656),
             ("rick.exe", 4538565)])
```

Note in particular the missing comma after `("terry.dmg", 54485656)`.